# Python iterate over regex condition to replace column's values

Tags: python, pandas, loops, replace

Suppose I have a non-standardized dataframe with keywords like this:

```
data = pd.DataFrame({'tool_description':['bond assy fixture', 'pierce die', 'cad geometrical non-template',
                                         '707 bond assy fixture', 'john pierce die', '123 cad geometrical non-template',
                                         'jjashd bond assy fixture', '10481 pierce die', '81235 cad geometrical non-template']})
```

Dataframe:

| tool_description |
| --- |
| bond assy fixture |
| pierce die |
| cad geometrical non-template |
| 707 bond assy fixture |
| john pierce die |
| 123 cad geometrical non-template |
| jjashd bond assy fixture |
| 10481 pierce die |
| 81235 cad geometrical non-template |

As you can see, the keywords, in this case, are bond assy fixture, pierce, and cad geometrical non-template.
I want to replace those values based on their keywords to have a standardized data. So I worked on a workaround like this:

```
# Pull the data matching my regex condition
X = data.loc[data.tool_description.str.contains((r"\b(bond assy fixture)\b"), case=False, regex=True), :]

# Replace values by a standardized name
X['tool_description] = 'bond assy fixture'

# Pull index from X dataset
index_list = X.tool_description.index.tolist()

# Create empty column in the original dataset
data['standardized_column'] = ""

# Loop to fill new column with a standardized description
for index in index_list:
    data.loc[index, 'standardized_column'] = 'bond assy fixture'
```

Output:

| tool_description | standardized_column |
| --- | --- |
| bond assy fixture | bond assy fixture |
| pierce die | nan |
| cad geometrical non-template | nan |
| 707 bond assy fixture | bond assy fixture |
| john pierce die | nan |
| 123 cad geometrical non-template | nan |
| jjashd bond assy fixture | bond assy fixture |
| 10481 pierce die | nan |
| 81235 cad geometrical non-template | nan |

This works fine, however for one condition, and I need to make a loop of all these for hundreds of regex conditions. When I try to loop over the line where I use this line of code

```
conditions = ['a', 'b', 'c']
for i in conditions:
    X = data.loc[data.tool_description.str.contains((r"\b(i)\b"), case=False, regex=True), :]
```

I have a problem placing the regex condition as an iterator. When the loop extracts the str from the list of conditions it will pull it with the quotation mark.

Now that I have put you in context, I have the following questions:

1. Is there a simpler and elegant way to replace those values?
2. If not, how can I create a loop to iterate over that regex?

Thank you for your time and answers. I know I could have asked how to remove the quotation mark for iteration purposes using regex, but, I wanted to know also if there's another way to solve the general problem which is the replacement of values.

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do or what output you're hoping for

Comment: What do you mean by `it will pull it with the quotation mark.`   Can't see the  quotation mark you mentioned in the sample.

Comment: Note that you need a pair of word boundary `\b` around the keyword so that `pierce` won't match with eg.  `mpierce`.   Your original use of regex is right.  Just using Python checking like `StringA in StringB` would produce false match since `pierce in mpierce` is still true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could write a function to attempt to find the matching substring, and return `'nan'` if not found

```
def replace(s):
    keywords = ['bond assy fixture', 'pierce', 'cad geometrical non-template']
    try:
        return next(i for i in keywords if i in s)
    except StopIteration:
        return 'nan'
```

Then you can use `apply` to make this substitution

```
>>> data['standardized_column'] = data.tool_description.apply(replace)
>>> data
                     tool_description           standardized_column
0                   bond assy fixture             bond assy fixture
1                          pierce die                        pierce
2        cad geometrical non-template  cad geometrical non-template
3               707 bond assy fixture             bond assy fixture
4                     john pierce die                        pierce
5    123 cad geometrical non-template  cad geometrical non-template
6            jjashd bond assy fixture             bond assy fixture
7                    10481 pierce die                        pierce
8  81235 cad geometrical non-template  cad geometrical non-template
```

Instead of `if i in s` you could use a regex in the `replace` function as well if you need something more complex than a simple substring check.

Answer (score 0):

You are close to the solution, just minor touch-ups needed, as follows:

```
data['standardized_column'] = np.nan     # init column to NaN

for word in keywords:
    data.loc[data.tool_description.str.contains((rf"\b{word}\b"), case=False, regex=True), 'standardized_column'] = word
```

**Here, we use word boundary `\b` to enclose the keyword in the regex so that partial word match is avoided.  Eg.  'pierce' won't match with 'mpierce'.  Python test of `StringA in StringB` would produce false match since `pierce in mpierce` is True but not what we want to match.**

Result:

```
print(data)



                     tool_description           standardized_column
0                   bond assy fixture             bond assy fixture
1                          pierce die                        pierce
2        cad geometrical non-template  cad geometrical non-template
3               707 bond assy fixture             bond assy fixture
4                     john pierce die                        pierce
5    123 cad geometrical non-template  cad geometrical non-template
6            jjashd bond assy fixture             bond assy fixture
7                    10481 pierce die                        pierce
8  81235 cad geometrical non-template  cad geometrical non-template
```